# Resampling and registering image data - what do you do first?

Tags: dicom, resampling, image-registration

I have 2 medical image datasets for a given patient, each acquired at the same time, each with a different modality. The frame of reference or coordinate space is different for each dataset (and I don't know the origins). One dataset has smaller physical dimensions than the other, the voxel sizes, as well as the number of frames are also different. I want to resample and register the images, does it matter which I do first?

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you resize the images first. This is because image registration algorithms will try to find a transformation that optimizes the match of the images. If you know the proper size of the images, it will be easier for the algorithms to find such transformation.